# Can animation be created in flex

Tags: apache-flex

Can animation be created in Flex without using Flash at all?

Answer (score 0):

Why not!

http://evtimmy.com/2010/04/two-examples-of-layout-animations/

BTW, in Flex you "render" a flash object: you can start either from scratch, or if you prefer by using something in flash and something not:

- http://sujitreddyg.wordpress.com/2008/01/02/creating-and-importing-flash-assets-into-flex/
- http://raghuonflex.wordpress.com/2008/03/27/flash-for-flex-developers-i-importing-artwork-from-flash-cs3-into-flex/

Rest (actionscript) should really be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Flex is a library built on top of Flash. If you are using Flex, you are using Flash.